# Powershell splatting a nested hash table

Tags: powershell, parameter-splatting

I have a function that returns a complex nested hash table data structure, where part of it forms the arguments for a further function call, and part of it is strings for reporting errors that result in the arguments not being populated.
Ideally I would like to splat just the arguments hash table, but I am starting to think that can't be done.
So, an example of the basic problem looks like this...

```
function Test {
    param (
        [String]$A,
        [String]$B,
        [String]$C
    )
    Write-Host "A: $A"
    Write-Host "B: $B"
    Write-Host "C: $C"
}

$data = @{
    arguments = @{
        A = 'A string'
        B = 'Another string'
        C = 'The last string'
    }
    kruft = 'A string that doesn not need to get passed'
}
```

Ideally I want to splat `$data.arguments`, so something like this...
`Test @data.arguments`
But that doesn't work, resulting in the error

```
The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression. '@data' can be used only as an argument to a command. To 
reference variables in an expression use '$data'.
```

So I tried...
`Test @(data.arguments)`
Which results in the error

```
data.arguments : The term 'data.arguments' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I also tried...
`Test @($data.arguments)`
Which results in the whole hash table being passed as a single argument and the output is

```
A: System.Collections.Hashtable
B: 
C:
```

What DOES work is...

```
$arguments = $data.arguments
Test @arguments
```

Which has me thinking you really cannot splat anything but a simple variable that is an appropriate hash table. But, I am hoping someone can verify that is indeed true, or point out the solution I haven't come up with yet.
The actual code requires 5 arguments, with somewhat verbose names because I prefer descriptive names, so splatting is very much an appropriate solution. Needing to make a new variable with just the hash table to be passed isn't an issue, just wondering if it really is the only option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible.

Any variable (and only variables) provided with "@" instead of "$" for a function parameter is declared as TokenKind "SplattedVariable".

See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.language.tokenkind?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0

**PS:**
Some quick tests from my side which could have succeed (apart from PS design):

```bsh
Write-Host 'Test 1' -ForegroundColor Yellow
Test @$data.arguments

Write-Host 'Test 2' -ForegroundColor Yellow
Test @$($bla = $data.arguments)

Write-Host 'Test 3' -ForegroundColor Yellow
Test @$bla = $data.arguments

Write-Host 'Test 4' -ForegroundColor Yellow
Test @$bla = $data.arguments.GetEnumerator()

Write-Host 'Test 5' -ForegroundColor Yellow
Test @$($data.arguments.GetEnumerator())
```

... but they didn't.

Comment: Thanks for the verification. I figured that was going to be the reality.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot claim to fully understand what you're attempting, but here are a couple of solutions that might help.

Your `Test` function is expecting three strings, but I don't see anything in your example that satisfies that. I would either change it to accept a `Hashtable` (which is the data type in question) or have it accept a string array and pass `$data.arguments.values`

Using a `Hashtable`:

```
function Test {
  param (
    [Hashtable]$hash
  )

  write-host $hash.A
  write-host $hash.B
  write-host $hash.C
}

Test $data.arguments
```

Using a `String` array:

```
function Test {
  param (
    [String[]]$a
  )

  $a | % { write-host $_ }
}

Test $data.arguments.values
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a totally artificial way (more of a hack) of doing this but you could pass it as a hash table then self-call with the arguments splatted

```
function Test {
    param (
    [Parameter()]
        [hashtable]$ht,
        [String]$A,
        [String]$B,
        [String]$C
    )
    if($null -eq $ht){
        Write-Host "A: $a" 
        Write-Host "B: $B" 
        Write-Host "C: $C" 
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "ht.A: $($ht.a)" 
        Test -a $($ht.A+ " new blob")  -b $ht.B -c $ht.C
        Test @ht
    }
}

$tdata = @{
    arguments = @{
        A = 'A string'
        B = 'Another string'
        C = 'The last string'
    }
    kruft = 'A string that doesn not need to get passed'
}

Write-Host 'Test ht' -ForegroundColor Yellow
Test -ht $tdata.arguments
```